# If $1$ boy and $1$ girl are selected at random, what is the probability that both of them scores $90$ marks above?

Tags: probability

> There are $25$ boys and $15$ girls in a class.
>   $5$ boys and $1$ girl has got $90$ marks above in exam.
>   If $1$ boy and $1$ girl are selected at random, what is the probability that both of them scores $90$ marks above?

How do I find the total possible outcome and favourable outcome?

Answer (score 2):

Let start with an easier scenario, suppose we have 3 boys and 2 girls,

$B_1$ $B_2$ $B_3$ $G_1$ $G_2$

If 1 boy and 1 girl are selected, the number of possible combinations should be

3 (3 boys $B_1$ $B_2$ $B_3$) $\times$ 2 (for each boy $B_i$, he can form a combination with $G_1$ or $G_2$)

{$B_1$, $G_1$}

{$B_1$, $G_2$}

{$B_2$, $G_1$}

$\vdots$

{$B_3$, $G_2$}

---

So, come to your question,

The number of all possible outcomes (1 boy and 1 girl) $= 25(15) = 375$

The number of all favourable outcomes (1 boy who got 90 marks above and 1 girl who got 90 marks above) $= 5(1) = 5$

The probability that both the selected boy and girl score 90 marks above $= 5 / 375 = 1/75$

---

Question 2: If two students are selected, both scores 90 marks above, what is the probability for that?

Simpler scenario:

$S_1$ $S_2$ $S_3$ $S_4$ $S_5$

If 2 students are selected, the number of possible combination:

5 (5 students) $\times$ 4 (4 left after picking one)

But notice that {$S_1$, $S_2$}, {$S_2$, $S_1$} are regarded as the same combination, thus the number of possible outcomes should be 5(4) divided by 2 i.e. 5(4) / 2 which is ${5 \choose 2}$ or $C^5_2$ or $C^2_5$ (which means the number of combination if we choose 2 from 5, ordering does not matter)

---

Going back to question 2,

The number of all possible outcomes (two students are selected) $= 40(39) / 2 = 780$

The number of all favourable outcomes (two selected students scores 90 marks above) $= 5(4) / 2 = 10$

The probability that both the two selected student score 90 marks above $= 10 / 780 = 1/78$

Actually, if you don't care about the issue that {$S_1$, $S_2$}, {$S_2$, $S_1$} are the same, you can also obtain the same probability using 5(4) and 40(39).

Comment: @jen Yes because you have only one girl scores 90 marks above.

Comment: Thanks kitman.  You quoted scenario is easier to understand.

Comment: One more, if two students are selected, both scores 90 marks above, what is the probability for that?

Comment: @jen You have 6 students score 90 marks above, if one of them is selected, only 5 left. Thus, the number of favourable outcomes is 6(5).

Comment: Sorry, so the probability is 6(5) / 375 ?

Comment: @jen I have edited my answer, please check.

Comment: You misread the question.  Note that one boy and one girl are selected.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I have solved the question for one boy and one girl and OP later asked me how to find the probability if two students are selected, both scores 90 marks above.

Answer (score 1):

We are selecting one of $25$ boys and one of $15$ girls, so the number of possible outcomes is 
$$\binom{25}{1}\binom{15}{1}$$
To obtain a favourable outcome, we must select one of the five boys who received $90$ marks above and the only girl who received $90$ marks above.  Hence, the number of favourable outcomes is 
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{1}{1}$$
The probability that both the selected boy and selected girl received $90$ marks above is therefore
$$\frac{\dbinom{5}{1}\dbinom{1}{1}}{\dbinom{25}{1}\dbinom{15}{1}}$$